# Parsing .thrift file to list service and their function names

Tags: json, parsing, thrift

What could be the efficient way to parse a .thrift file to extract services and their corresponding function names?

For eample, I want to list the service name - PostStorageService and its functions StorePost.. ReadPost etc..

I have not found any working tool so far! to parse the .thrift file. I tried --gen json but it does not seem to be working.

Thanks!

```
service PostStorageService {
  void StorePost(
    1: i64 req_id,
    2: Post post,
    3: map<string, string> carrier
  ) throws (1: ServiceException se)

  Post ReadPost(
    1: i64 req_id,
    2: i64 post_id,
    3: map<string, string> carrier
  ) throws (1: ServiceException se)

  list<Post> ReadPosts(
    1: i64 req_id,
    2: list<i64> post_ids,
    3: map<string, string> carrier
  ) throws (1: ServiceException se)
}
```

Comment: "*it does not seem to be working*"   -- works for me.

Comment: May I ask what the desired outcome is? What do you want to do with that information, assumed you have it extracted somehow?